# R: Running multiple tests by selecting (and increasing) number of fixed data points selected - Followup

Tags: r, simulation

This is a follow-up from a previous post ([R: Running multiple tests by selecting (and increasing) number of fixed data points selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898925/r-running-multiple-tests-by-selecting-and-increasing-number-of-fixed-data-poi)):
I have a dataframe (saved as data.csv) that looks something like this:

| person | outcome | baseline_post | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | baseline | BL_1 |
| 1 | 1 | baseline | BL_2 |
| 1 | 0 | baseline | BL_3 |
| 1 | 2 | baseline | BL_4 |
| 1 | 4 | post | post_1 |
| 1 | 3 | post | post_2 |
| 1 | 4 | post | post_3 |
| 1 | 6 | post | post_4 |
| 2 | 1 | baseline | BL_1 |
| 2 | 2 | baseline | BL_2 |
| 2 | 0 | baseline | BL_3 |
| 2 | 1 | baseline | BL_4 |
| 2 | 3 | post | post_1 |
| 2 | 2 | post | post_2 |
| 2 | 4 | post | post_3 |
| 2 | 3 | post | post_4 |

And same as the previous post, the purpose is to try iterate a same test (can be any test) over the desired fixed combinations arranged across time,
i.e., For each participant, compare outcome(s) at BL_1 against post_1, then BL_1 and BL_2 against post_1 ...  BL_1, BL_2, BL_3 and BL_4 against post_1 etc.

Basically all combinations increasing in the number of weeks tested before (BL_1 to 4) and after (post_1 to 2) treatment.

I tried modifying from @Caspar V.'s codes (thanks @Caspar V. for your previous response):

```
#creating pre/post data frames for later use
df <- read.csv("C:/Users/data.csv")
df_baseline <- filter(df, baseline_post == "baseline") %>% 
                  rename(baseline = baseline_post) %>% 
                  rename(time_baseline = time)
df_post <- filter(df, baseline_post == "post") %>% 
                  rename(post = baseline_post) %>% 
                  rename(time_post = time)

#generate a list of desired comparisons
comparisons = list()

for(a_len in seq_along(df_baseline$baseline)) for(b_len in seq_along(df_post$post)){
  comp = list(baseline = head(df_baseline$time_baseline, a_len), post = head(df_post$time_post, b_len))
  comparisons = append(comparisons, list(comp))
}

#KIV create combined df for time if required
df_baseline_post <- cbind(df_baseline$time_baseline, df_post$time_post)
colnames(df_baseline_post) = c("time_baseline", "time_post")

#iterate through list of comparisons
for(df_baseline_post in comparisons) {
  
  cat(df_baseline_post$time_baseline, 'versus', df_baseline_post$time_post, '\n')
#this is where your analysis goes, poisson_frequencies being a test function I created
  poisson_frequencies(df)
}
```

This is unfortunately my output, which are 16 "versus-es", because there are 16 possible combinations based on the above data:

```
versus 
 versus 
 versus 
 versus 
 versus 
 versus 
...
 versus
```

I am not sure what went wrong.  Appreciate any input.  I am new when it comes to programming in R.

Comment: If you could put your csv online for such questions, hat'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of problems; the following should get you back on track. Good luck!

### 1)

You're getting 64 comparisons in `comparisons`, not 16. If you would just look at the contents of `comparisons` you'd see that. It's because you have duplicates in `df$time`. You'll need to remove them first:

```
#generate a list of desired comparisons
groupA = unique(df_baseline$time_baseline)
groupB = unique(df_post$time_post)

comparisons = list()

for(a_len in seq_along(groupA)) for(b_len in seq_along(groupB)) {

  comp = list(baseline = head(groupA, a_len), post = head(groupB, b_len))
  comparisons = append(comparisons, list(comp))

}
```

### 2)

The following block is not used, and the variable `df_baseline_post` is overwritten in the for-loop after it, so you can just remove this:

```
#KIV create combined df for time if required
# df_baseline_post <- cbind(df_baseline$time_baseline, df_post$time_post)
# colnames(df_baseline_post) = c("time_baseline", "time_post")
```

### 3)

You're executing `poisson_frequencies(df)` every time, but not doing anything with the output. That's why you're not seeing anything. You'll need to put a print() around it: `print(poisson_frequencies(df))`. Of course `df` is also not the data you want to work with, but I hope you already knew that.

### 4)

`df_baseline_post$time_baseline` and `df_baseline_post$time_post` don't exist. The loop should be:

```
for(df_baseline_post in comparisons) {
  cat(df_baseline_post$baseline, 'versus', df_baseline_post$post, '\n')
  print(poisson_frequencies(df))
}
```